# not able to boot in 21.10 on intel core i9-11900T

Tags: boot, intel-graphics

I have tried the option:

```
i915.force_probe=4c8a
```

in grub menu but I get black screen.
I am not able to boot.

Does anyone have any solution to the problem?

thanks

Comment: Can you boot into a live DVD/USB?

Comment: no. I cannot do it from the live image, from the USB stick. After I edit the first item of the menu with 'e' and add the above option, then press agaian CTRL-X the screen remaiins black.

Comment: Try the `nomodeset` option

Comment: I've already tried. It does not work either.